# I created an array of "ducks" and now I want to create a list of all Ducks which are older than a specified age

Tags: java, arrays

I created an array of "ducks" and now I want to create a list of all Ducks which are older than a specified age. This is what I got so far I have a main Duck class and where I a Duck is defined by (String name, int x, int y, int speed, int age)

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Flock {
    private ArrayList<Duck> myDucks;
    public Flock(){
        myDucks = new ArrayList<Duck>();
    }
    public Flock(int numberOfDucks){
        myDucks = new ArrayList<Duck>();
        for (int i=0; i< numberOfDucks; i++){
            if (Math.random()>0.5){
                //Create a pintail duck and add it to the flock
                PintailDuck foo= new PintailDuck("PintailDuck", (int)(100*Math.random()),(int)(100*Math.random()), (int)(10*Math.random()), (int)(30*Math.random()) );
                myDucks.add(foo);
                }
            else {
                //Create a mallard duck and add it to the flock
                MallardDuck foo= new MallardDuck("MallardDuck",(int)(100*Math.random()), (int)(100*Math.random()), (int)(100*Math.random()),(int)(100*Math.random()));
                myDucks.add(foo);
            }
    }

    public ArrayList<Duck> olderThan(int someAge){
        //Create a Result ArrayList
        olderThan = new ArrayList<Duck>(someAge);

        //Loop over all the Ducks
        for(int i=0; i< numberOfDucks; i++){
            if (myDucks[i]== someAge){
                return i;


            }
        }

            //Test if the current Duck is older than someAge
            //if so add it to the Result ArrayList



        //Return the Return ArrayList of Ducks older than someAge

    }



    }
    public void add(Duck aDuck){
        myDucks.add(aDuck);
    }

    public void quack(){
        for (Duck theDuck : myDucks){
            theDuck.quack();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return myDucks.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the program work?

Comment: @xpda it does not work

Comment: Does the program compile?  it doesn't look like it should, and the compiler should tell you why (or at least where to start!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what's going on here, but this part looks weird to me:

```
   public ArrayList<Duck> olderThan(int someAge){
        //Create a Result ArrayList
        olderThan = new ArrayList<Duck>(someAge);
        //Loop over all the Ducks
        for(int i=0; i< numberOfDucks; i++){
            if (myDucks[i]== someAge){
                return i;
            }
        }
            //Test if the current Duck is older than someAge
            //if so add it to the Result ArrayList
        //Return the Return ArrayList of Ducks older than someAge
    }
```

The signature says that it will return a list of Ducks, but you're returning an int. Also, your equality test is between a Duck (`myDucks[i]`) and an int (`someAge`). And further, you're passing `someAge` into the constructor of an `ArrayList`, which doesn't make sense -- it's an age, not the number of ducks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework and is full of problems.

But your main problem is here:

return i;

I won't explain why as this is homework.